# Would water-affecting spells work on the River Styx?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, baldurs-gate-descent-into-avernus

Would spells like *Control Water*, *Shape Water*, and *(Create or) Destroy Water* work on water(?) from the River Styx?
In other words, does "water" in Styx count as water?

I'm asking in context of D&D 5e. The only source regarding Styx I know of is *Descent into Avernus*, and I didn't find any response to my question there.

Comment: Is there a specific source book for a setting that you're using with rules, mechanics, or a description for the river Styx? Or are you asking based on the river as described in Greek mythology?

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Im assuming it’s *Descent into Avernus* since that’s the only 5e adventure featuring the River.

Comment: I'm interested in various interpretations but yeah I'm mostly asking in context of Descent into Avernus since that is the only source related to Styx I know of.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### You could definitely control, shape, or destroy River Styx water.

The rules on the River Styx in *Descent into Avernus* consistently refer to the liquid as water, and while it lists many other effects, none of them prevent these spells from working:

> Simply tasting or touching its **waters** can shatter a creature’s intellect and personality, as well as strip away its memories...
>
> ...A feebleminded creature can drink from the Styx and swim in its **waters** without suffering any additional deleterious effects...
>
> [...]
>
> **Water** taken from the River Styx loses its potency after 24 hours, becoming a harmless, foul-tasting liquid. However, arcanaloths, night hags, and other fell creatures might know rituals that can prolong the **water**’s potency, at your discretion.

### You probably can't use *create or destroy water* to conjure it

> You create up to 10 gallons of clean water within range in an open container.

I wouldn't consider water from the River Styx to be "clean water" and, regardless, the spell creates water whole cloth; it doesn't conjure water from a chosen location.